# Color syntax highlighting in Bash while using R

Tags: r

I'm running R in Bash under Ubuntu. Is there a way to use color syntax highlighting in Bash while running R? I'd be very thankful for any information on the subject, and hope the question is not annoyingly ignorant.

Comment: If there is, I'm all ears.  But you'll probably be better served using an R gui like RStudio or a nice editor.  Personally, I use emacs with ESS (emacs speaks statistics) and develop all my R code and scripting there.  [Current Emacs 24 Release for Ubuntu 12.04](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs)

Comment: Thanks! RStudio is a great Bash-external solution I was not aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `colorout` package.

Comment: Thanks! While `colorout` solves the problem with the output in a beautiful way, I wonder if there is another package allowing color syntax highlighting of the commands while they're being typed in.